# "Database is locked" in delete operation in my sqlite

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have a function like this for delete table row in my apps, but I have an error that said "database is locked".

```
- (BOOL) deleteByCaption:(NSString *)registerCaption
 {
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM tabelA WHERE CONTENT_CAPTION = \"%@\"", registerCaption];

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    //        NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
            return YES;
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            return NO;
        }
    }
    sqlite3_reset(statement);
}
return NO;
}
```

Comment: after put finalize statment please remove build from simulator clrear all catch from directory and rennin again.

Comment: Have you try to call this method from other method included one more database open code?

Comment: yeah, I have tried it, and still got this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `sqlite3_finalize()`. Look at //PUT HERE part in following code.

```
- (BOOL) deleteByCaption:(NSString *)registerCaption
{
    BOOL isDeleted = NO; //EDIT
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM tabelA WHERE CONTENT_CAPTION = \"%@\"", registerCaption];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        //        NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
            if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
                isDeleted = YES;
                //return YES; //EDIT
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                //return NO; //EDIT
            }
        }
        sqlite3_reset(statement);
        sqlite3_finalize(statement); //PUT HERE
        sqlite3_close(database); //EDIT
    }
    //return NO; //EDIT
    return isDeleted; //EDIT
}
```

EDIT:

Try to set one variable to return.
*Look at the edited portion in above code. Search for //EDIT.*

Comment: bhargavi its s `statement` not `database` `sqlite3_finalize(statement);`  instead of `sqlite3_finalize(database);`

Comment: still the same as before issue.. "database is locked".

Comment: @Template09 check your whole code for finalize and close. It must be there before you fire query

Answer (score 0):

In `deleteByCaption` function too, You are returning from function without closing data base.

You should write following statements before writing `"RETURN YES"` or `"RETURN NO"`

```
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(database);
```

Please check all functions where your have used `sqlite3_open()` function.

and make sure to write `sqlite3_close()` function before returning from that function.

Comment: But I call another function that delete all rows, its okay, but I just want to call this function get this issue?